# Ignore 4xx Enhanced Health Rule causes AWS EB console configuration page error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Following the instructions at [Configuring Enhanced Health Rules Using a Config Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-rules.html#health-enhanced-rules.configdocument) to ignore application HTTP 4xx errors using the ".ebextensions/YAML/JSON" method, specifically, the following has been added to ".ebextensions/00_option_settings.config":

```
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system
    option_name: ConfigDocument
    value: {
      "Rules": {
        "Environment": {
          "Application": {
            "ApplicationRequests4xx": {
              "Enabled": false
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Version": 1
    }
```

With this configuration, a deploy to elastic beanstalk succeeds and seems to have the desired effect, but then when visiting the env's "configuration" page (i.e. "https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home?region=us-east-1#/environment/dashboard?applicationName=my-app&environmentId=e-12345678"  in the EB console, an error occurs:

[image]

I have tried quoting/escaping etc the JSON embedded within the YAML, but to no effect.

From the command line, `eb config` works ok:

```
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system:
    ConfigDocument: '{"Version":1,"Rules":{"Environment":{"Application":{"ApplicationRequests4xx":{"Enabled":false}}}}}'
    HealthCheckSuccessThreshold: Ok
    SystemType: enhanced
```

Comment: This seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Mine looks like this and it is working correctly.

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system
    option_name: ConfigDocument
    value: {"Rules": {"Environment": {"Application": {"ApplicationRequests4xx": {"Enabled": false}}}},"Version": 1}
```

Comment: Yes, that's effectively the same as what I had (formatting aside). I think there may have been a bug on the AWS EB side - which was fixed (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664509/ignore-4xx-enhanced-health-rule-causes-aws-eb-console-configuration-page-error/55581549#comment90618225_51664509)